# Getting into the 131st AES convention

Tags: aes

$509.

That is the price for non-members who want to see more than the exhibits. I had the privilege of attending the 127th AES convention, but I was a student and a member at that time, so I qualified for their MASSIVE discount ($99 for full entry). However, being that I graduated this May I have not renewed my membership (expensive), and I no longer qualify as a student. So here's my question: Have any of you figured out a way to (legally) gain access to the convention's seminars on the cheap? Secret loopholes? Generous people who have too much money? craigslist? Any tips would be appreciated, though it won't surprise me if the simple answer is "$509".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press passes for events like these do exist, but you'll have a hard time getting one if you're not with an established outlet. Vendors frequently have exhibit passes that they'll give away, but I've never heard of them giving away full conference passes. I believe you can get a free pass if you're a presenter as well (anyone like to confirm/discredit that one?).

That about empties my knowledge bank on the subject of discounted passes. Once you've been a member though, it's easy to renew. Since you've been a student member before, you probably shouldn't have any issues getting in as an associate member. That will get you a bit of discount; which is a little more than the cost of the lowest priced type - "online journal only." Beyond that, I believe that you're stuck with the full $509.

If you are in the New York City area, becoming a member (even associate) could be very much worth it...regardless of whether you can afford to go to the conference or not. From what I've heard, it's one of the more active chapters. Getting information about and attending their local events would be well worth your time.

Comment: I may do that then for the NYC chapter, and the pass :-) . I was a part of the Boston chapter, but they weren't very active, nor helpful...

Comment: @Mies B. - yeah, the D.C. chapter sends something out once every 8-9 months. that's weird about the boston one though, they used to be pretty active when i was there a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to be a full-time student to get the discount? And is it limited to specific schools / majors?

Maybe start plugging away at requirements for your next degree, one class at a time (if it'll get you the discount, or if it's something you actually want to do).

(Also, while you're at it, get your year of free Amazon Prime and download a bunch of student software with your .edu email address.)